# Django admin page is missing images/css/js

Tags: python, django

I have found a few questhons re my problem, you the solutions didn't help me so I started a new question. Basically that's how I see the admin page 
[image: no css/no js/ no images]

Apache's config:

```
<VirtualHost *.*.*.*:80>
    ServerName ********.org
    ServerAdmin ****@******.org

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webproxy/webproxy/wsgi.py

    DocumentRoot /var/www/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/

    ErrorLog /var/www/webproxy/apache/error.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/www/webproxy/apache/access.log combined

Alias /media/ "/var/www/webproxy/media/"

<Directory "/var/www/webproxy/media/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/webproxy/static/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is what I have in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from core import urls as core_urls

from settings import MEDIA_ROOT, WEBPROXY_MEDIA_ROOT

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^ui/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': WEBPROXY_MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/webproxy/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/webproxy/static/'
WEBPROXY_MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/webproxy/static/media/'
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your `settings.py` values for `MEDIA_ROOT` and `WEBPROXY_MEDIA_ROOT`?

Comment: Are the Django admin media files copied (ideally symbolically linked) under any of the above static files locations? Edited my answer.

Comment: yes, all of them (symlinked) :). I trying to solve the issue, so currently all of those static folreds have 'admin' folder with all files I need, but they're still not displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be serving the static files via `django.views.static.serve` in production as that is meant to be used *only* for local development (read docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#django.views.static.serve)):

> There may be files other than your project's static assets that, for
>   convenience, you'd like to have Django serve for you in local
>   development.

Second, your Django Admin static files reside under the location Django was installed at. I find using directly these files a better solution than copying (or symlink'ing) the Django admin static files under my own static files directories.

Example Django static files location on my server:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
```

Therefore in your web server config you have to point the url `/media/admin` to

```
[my_django_location]/contrib/admin/static/admin/
```

If you're doing things locally, then you might need another entry in your `urls.py`:

```
(r'^admin/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', '/path/to/your/admin/files/'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your first advise, I will follow it when I move this app to production mode. Re second, i have created a symbollical link `ln -s /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ admin` to all static folders. This didn't help :(

Comment: @KennyPowers Try to access an individual css file from the browser; might be something wrong with the structure of your files on disk rather than Django static file routing.

Comment: `Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://****.org/static/admin/css/base.css` that's what I got...

Comment: @KennyPowers Updated my answer - see last part.

Comment: yeah that must be ok for development, but what if I want to change it to production mode :(

Comment: @KennyPowers Production mode is easier! In your `urls.py` serve those static files only when `settings.DEBUG==True`; this will avoid exposing those URLs in production. In production use your Web server (Apache or Nginx) to serve static files; you'll find loads of articles describing in detail how to serve a static file location via any web server, and related techniques, i.e. *caching*. Enjoy!

Comment: I can't set this up in production mode. Still getting 404. I have checked chmod, it's ok also. I'm lost

Comment: @KennyPowers You have to set Apache/Nginx to serve static files from a specific location where the server has access. I.e. it must be something with your server config.

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was in httpd config, there was no alias on `/static/` folder.